# Gnome: Map AltGr key to Alt

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, gnome, keyboard-layout

I have an annoying UK keyboard which has an <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key where the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is on a US keyboard. This is really annoying when using Gnome which makes heavy use of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd> key.

Does anyone know how I can map the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmodmap`

The 'shift, lock, control, modN' on the left are what X sees and cares about.  The keysyms on the right map to them.  `Mode_switch` [is your AltGr key](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xmodmap.html).  Move it to join the others at `mod1`:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear mod5'
xmodmap -e 'add mod1 = Mode_switch'
```

Comment: No that didn't work for me, fired up emacs and AltGr-v gives me “ instead of scrolling the page up as it would with alt-v.

Comment: Those specific commands didn't work, or looking at the output of 'xmodmap' and moving the keysym didn't work?  You can use 'xev' to help with this: run it, mouse over the window, and press modded keys.

Comment: The command worked and here is the output of the xmodmap:
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)

Comment: Sorry for the mess, is seems like this site strips line breaks from comments.

Comment: That output shows that you haven't cleared mod5, and that you haven't added Mode_switch to mod1.  xmodmap -e changes like this are temporal: you can blow them away with setxkbmap, for instance.

Comment: Sorry there was a reboot between when I entered the commands and recorded the output of xmodmap, maybe the changes aren't persistent? Anyway I've entered the command again and now xmodmap look like this:

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5 

So the changes are showing, but if I still can't do CTRL-ALT-DEL in Gnome or use meta commands in emacs using AltGr.

Comment: And if you also  xmodmap -e 'add mod1 = ISO_Level3_Shift'  ?

Comment: Yes thanks alot, that nailed it! Are those changes persistent or will I loose them when I reboot?

Comment: They are not persistent.  I've put them in ~/.xsession for xdm setups, but http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/debian_linux_desktop_survival_guide/GDM_Startup.shtml suggests that you put them in ~/.gnomerc

Comment: Ok I've now noticed a problem, gnome is behaving like the alt key is constantly pressed, when I hit v for example in nautilus it opens up the View menu.

Comment: If you're sure that this is related, you might: try removing the mode_switch keysym; change the keycode to generate Alt or Meta keysyms instead of dealing with the modifier table at all (xmodmap usage is similar: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 123 = 4 5'` -- look through `xmodmap -pke`)

Comment: Ok cracked it with xmodmap -e 'keycode 203 = NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L'. If anyone else is trying this your key might not be 203, look for the key which calls Mode_switch and change it to the above.

Answer (score 11):

[gnome-tweak-tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/GnomeTweakTool?action=show&redirect=GnomeTweakTool) lets you do this with a GUI:

Typing -> Key to choose 3rd level -> Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level

Comment: Link only answer say what??

Comment: In German: "Verhalten der Alt/Windows-Tasten" -> "Alt und Meta befinden sich auf den Alt-Tasten"

Comment: This is working in Ubuntu 20.04 in year 2020 :)

Comment: ^ This is the best solution.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 It is Tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options

Answer (score 8):

For those UK users still pulling their hairs out, this worked for me:

```
xmodmap -e "clear mod5"
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_L"
```

Explanation: The first line removes the current behaviour of your AltGr (which is assigned to the mod5 modifier). The second takes the AltGr key (which on my keyboard produces a keycode of 108), and maps that to whatever keycode your Alt_L key is mapped to.

If you have no idea what is going on with keycodes and keysyms, I found this [xmodmap introduction](http://rollingrelease.com/system/2010/09/xmodmap-hints-and-tips) very useful.

Comment: For non UK users: This worked on my german keyboard as well, while the gnome-tweaks setting did not fwiw. Ubuntu 20.10 variant (pop os).

Answer (score 1):

====Change AltGr to Alt in Gnome

Click on Show Applications > Settings > Keyboard > In Special Character Entry click on Alternate Characters Key > Put Use layout default to Off > Click on None.

In  Special Character Entry also click on Compose Key > Put Use layout default to Off > Click on Left Alt > Put Use layout default to On.

To test if it works correctly start the Terminal. Write a short text, for example “Write a short text.” Press Right Alt and B at the same time. If the the cursor goes back a word it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers still do not work you then run `xev -event keyboard` (you may need to install it first) and press AltGr with the Event Tester window in focus. You should see something like the following in the shell.

```
KeyPress event, serial 163, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 21667560, (151,737), root:(1111,764),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

On the third line it gives you the keycode and keysym name, which in my case is `ISO_Level3_Shift`. Now run `xmodmap` and check the output before doing

```
xmodmap -e "remove mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
xmodmap -e "add mod1 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

where `ISO_Level3_Shift` should be replaced with the correct key symbol if necessary. Finally you need to add this to your user rc script to make it persistent.