# How to remap Alt Gr key to Alt key globally in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I don't need the Alt Gr key, and I've noticed that I'm unable to do Alt Gr + Left key to go back in a normal web browser which is very frustrating.

Is there a way to remap the Alt Gr key to just Alt? I already tried AutoKey for Ubuntu but it doesn't detect the Alt Gr key at all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gnome: Map AltGr key to Alt](https://superuser.com/questions/53092/gnome-map-altgr-key-to-alt)

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be already answered here: [Gnome: Map AltGr key to Alt](https://superuser.com/questions/53092/gnome-map-altgr-key-to-alt)

I believe [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xmodmap.1.html) is the way to go.

You can find several examples of how to use `xmodmap` (depending on your keyboard configuration) on the referenced answer page.

You can also check out [gnome tweak tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweak-tool), which provides a GUI for doing exactly that.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Here we try to make sure each answer fully answers the question at hand, so while links to other resources are helpful, it's best if you at least quote the relevant portions, or restate the information this question needs in your own words. Anything else is better left as a comment (you will need a bit more reputation for that). I see that this question may be a duplicate, if it is it may be closed.